# What is right use of service object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ruby on rails.

I want to know how to use Service object Ruby on Rails style.

I read articles about service object in ruby.

next article tell "Rule 1: Only One Public Method per Service Object"
https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-service-objects-tutorial
but why should have just one public method?

next article tell different.(I think similar to spring, so it seems that service has more than 1 public method)
https://dev.to/mikamai/effective-service-objects-in-ruby-2ga0

I don't know what is rails style service object.
I don't know why service object should have one public method.

Comment: I believe that the only one public method principle is related to Single-responsibility principle. So it is easier to test and control a service. In the second article, I don't see multiple public methods in code examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Moved comment to answer for formatting.)

The reason for a single method is described in the link:

> Service objects are single business actions.

This is an opinion, and dependent on your view of what a "service object" is. This article is wrapping up isolated functionality.

The second article is groups functionality (in a module, not a class).

Which makes more sense? *shrug* Depends. There's no intrinsically right or wrong answer.